# Update Statement and ExecuteNonQuery Doesnot return C#, MySQL

Tags: c#, mysql

In my C#,asp.net application, im inserting field values in to MySQl and later im updating fiels values after editing. I used below code. its get executed but values are not get added in Database. And also i used

> numRowsUpdated = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

But in debugger windows, it shows as

> The name 'numRowsUpdated' does not exist in the current context

My code:

```
 protected void UpdateBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            int numRowsUpdated = -1;
            string Query = "UPDATE employee SET  EmployeeName=@a,EmpID =@b,Designation =@c,JoiningDate=@d,BankName =@e,AccountNumber = @f,Pancard =@g,PFNumber=@h WHERE id = @i" ;
            if (GlobalCS.OpenConnection() == true)
            {                    
                MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(Query, GlobalCS.objMyCon);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("i", selectedid);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("a", NameTxt.Text);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("b", EmpidTxt.Text);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("c", DesgTxt.Text);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("d", JoinTxt.Text);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("e", BankTxt.Text);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("f", ACNoTxt.Text);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("g", PANTxt.Text);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("h", PFTxt.Text);
                numRowsUpdated = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery(); 
            } 
            GlobalCS.CloseConnection();                
        }
```

GridView selection:

```
protected void OnSelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            GridViewRow row = EmployeeGrid.SelectedRow;
            selectedid = Convert.ToInt32(row.Cells[1].Text);
            NameTxt.Text = row.Cells[2].Text;
            EmpidTxt.Text = row.Cells[3].Text;
          ...

        }
```

selectedid declaration:

```
namespace SimERP
{
    public partial class Employee : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        int selectedid = -1;
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            LoadEmployeeData();
        }
```

Comment: Where is `selectedid` coming from? I can not see it here. If there is no row with `id=selectedid` then nothing will be updated.

Comment: Yes. Insert query works fine. Values added using Insert query is available. Im using gridview selected row and all values are showed in text boxs ,then im editing some text box values and pressing update button to add a changed values.

Comment: For Piyush Parashar, protected void OnSelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            GridViewRow row = EmployeeGrid.SelectedRow;
            selectedid = Convert.ToInt32(row.Cells[1].Text);
            NameTxt.Text = row.Cells[2].Text;
            EmpidTxt.Text = row.Cells[3].Text;
            DesgTxt.Text = row.Cells[4].Text;          
            ...
        }

Comment: selectedid declared in top of page_load function.public partial class Employee : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        int selectedid = -1;
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

Comment: Post the code in the question it is not legible here.

Answer (score 1):

Code seems fine. You have to put `@` symbol with parameter names:

Example:

```
 cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@i", selectedid);
 cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@a", NameTxt.Text);
 cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@b", EmpidTxt.Text);
 cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@c", DesgTxt.Text);
```

**UPDATE**:

Seems like `if(!IsPostBack)` is also missing in Page_Load event:

```
namespace SimERP
{
    public partial class Employee : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        int selectedid = -1;
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (!IsPostBack)
            {
               LoadEmployeeData();
            }
        }
```